# Invalid `Podfile` file: uninitialized constant

Tags: ios, cocoapods, rename, uninitialized-constant

Adding identical pods to each target is redundant.

```
   def RedundantPod

        pod "Pod"
    end

    target 'targetOne' do
        RedundantPod
    end

    target 'targetTwo' do
        RedundantPod
    end
```

The following setup throws an error of type: `[ ! ] Invalid Podfile file: uninitialized constant`. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 6):

For future readers, the issue comes from the naming `RedundantPod` which shouldn't start with a capital `R`.

Indeed, names that start with capital letters are constants in Ruby. It's still possible to use a constant name for a method, but you won't be able to invoke it without parentheses, because the interpeter will look-up for the name as a constant.

You need to either explicitly call the method:

```rb
def RedundantPod
   pod "Pod"
end

target 'targetOne' do
   RedundantPod()
end
```

or rename it without capitalization:

```rb
def redundantPod
   pod "Pod"
end

target 'targetOne' do
   redundantPod
end
```

Comment: This is really annoying, thanks for the solution, @Amaury, it works for me